# Resetter Can't Find Manifest

Tags: 20.04, files, reset

So I want to reset my Ubuntu 20.04 installation without reinstalling it, so I am going to use Resetter.  However, Resetter can't find the manifest file for the system.  I don't have good experience with VirtualBox, so I can't make a manifest for resetter.  Would it be a big issue if I used the 18.04 manifest file, and then updated?

Comment: Using obsolete "manifest" files for a system manipulation application is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: May I ask why? If they're for an older LTS system, I see no problem with using it, and then sudo apt update.